# python the following arguments are required

Tags: python

```py
#headers 
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
from pprint import pprint
import json
import argparse

def save_dataset(symbol, time_window):
    credentials = json.load(open('creds.json', 'r'))
    api_key = credentials['api key']
    print(symbol, time_window)
    ts = TimeSeries(key=api_key, output_format='pandas')
    if time_window == 'intraday':
        data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(
            symbol='MSFT', interval='1min', outputsize='full')
    elif time_window == 'daily':
        data, meta_data = ts.get_daily(symbol, outputsize='full')
    elif time_window == 'daily_adj':
        data, meta_data = ts.get_daily_adjusted(symbol, outputsize='full')

    pprint(data.head(10))

    data.to_csv(f'./{symbol}_{time_window}.csv')
```

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('symbol', type=str, help="the stock symbol you want to download")
    parser.add_argument('time_window', type=str, choices=[
                        'intraday', 'daily', 'daily_adj'], help="the time period you want to download the stock history for")

    namespace = parser.parse_args()
    save_dataset(**vars(namespace))
```

i get a save_data_to_csv.py: error: the following arguments are required: symbol, time_window
how do i solve this problem 
i included the header files

Comment: Pass in the required arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```
save_dataset(**namespace)
```

Parse_args return a dictionary, where keys are your variables and values are passed from the input. If you do vars(namespace) you got an error as a dictionary do not have `__dict__` attribute.

Note that you could also do like this, as your function take positional arguments.

```py
save_dataset(*namespace.values())
```

Comment: the same error .

Comment: @sandertuin how do you call your script? As well as print namespace, and see what is going on.

Comment: i use pycharm to write and run the script

Comment: @sandertuin OK, but you use args parser, so you script should be called like this "my_script.py symbol time_window". Of cource, replace  symbol and time_window by the value you want.

Comment: thanks it work or i cote new error but thanks